# How to display a YouTube Video in Jupyter Notebook by Clicking a Button Using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, random, video, youtube

I'm trying to display a random YouTube Video from a list of 2 videos in my Jupyter notebook by displaying a button and clicking it.

This will display a random video from the TODO list

```
import random
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
TODO =  (YouTubeVideo('-C-ic2H24OU', width=800, height=300), YouTubeVideo('NpPDgrbmAYQ', width=800, height=300))
random_choice_from_my_list = random.choice(TODO)
random_choice_from_my_list
```

This will display the button

```
import tkinter as tk
def TODO_ACTIVITY():
    random_choice_from_my_list   
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button = tk.Button(frame, 
                   text="TO DO", 
                   fg="black",
                   command=TODO_ACTIVITY)
button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Nothing happens when I click the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Bonus points if you can help me print a text label above the YouTube Video output

Comment: Did you try `display(random_choice_from_my_list)` inside `TODO_ACTIVITY()`?

Comment: @acw1668 It gives me:

  File "<ipython-input-2-1b9a106122c9>", line 4
    def TODO_ACTIVITY(display(random_choice_from_my_list)):
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Not inside the definition line, inside the function body.  Also you need to add `from IPython.display import display`.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. I ended up using def TODO_ACTIVITY():
    display(random.choice(TODO)) in order to accomplish what I needed. How can I mark your answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `IPython.display.display()` function to show the video:

```py
...
from IPython.display import display

...
def TODO_ACTIVITY():
    random_choice_from_my_list = random.choice(TODO)
    display(random_choice_from_my_list)
```